# Unable to change font of Vector element in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, vector, fonts

I am using Vector to add elements in a table in a blackberry project. The font does not seem to change programmatically. I have tested it in different screen blackberry phones. In BOLD & CURVE it seems fine, but in large screen phones like 9810 torch, 9790 BOLD, it takes some default font which is very big. Even if I change the font of the phone through setup, it changes the font of LabelFields and TextFields but applying FontFamily font does not reflect on Vector elements.

I am attaching the screenshots from 9800 & 9810...In 9800 it appears fine, in 9810, it looks big
[image]   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by making changes in RegionStyles. Initially we had given Font parameter as null. After changing it to appFont1 instead of null, the app font stopped overriding and works fine now.

```
    RegionStyles style = new RegionStyles(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(5,0,0,0), Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT), appFont1, null,null, RegionStyles.ALIGN_LEFT, RegionStyles.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int x = 0; x < vector.size(); x++) {
      FriendListObject b = (FriendListObject) vector.elementAt(x);
      name_ = b.getf_name().toString();
    }
TableRowManager row = new TableRowManager() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                 g.setBackgroundColor(0xa2b8c3);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                 g.setColor(0xe5e7e7);
                 g.clear();
                 super.paint(g);
            }
        };




LabelField name= new LabelField(name_+" :", DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS);
name.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN));

 row.add(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

same situation I am also faced then,I customised fontfamily for each resolution.for example

```
if (Display.getWidth()==480 && Display.getHeight()==360) {
   _custHeadNews = new CustTextField(_newsHead,30,0x05235b,TextField.FOCUSABLE);
   _custMainNews = new CustTextField(_newsMain,25,0x666666, RichTextField.FOCUSABLE);
   _custMetadata = new CustTextField(_metaData,15,0x666666,TextField.FOCUSABLE);
}
else if (Display.getWidth()==320 && Display.getHeight()==240) {
   _custHeadNews = new CustTextField(_newsHead,25,0x05235b,TextField.FOCUSABLE);
   _custMainNews = new CustTextField(_newsMain,15,0x666666, RichTextField.FOCUSABLE);
   _custMetadata = new CustTextField(_metaData,10,0x666666,TextField.FOCUSABLE);
}
```

bolded font size for different resolutions.